# Google Cloud Storage: file system limitations

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Assuming we use Google Cloud Storage for a Node.js web application, I was wondering if we still face the same problems when it comes to storing a massive amount of files. Usually you would have to take care to not exceeding a certain amount of files in each folder and not too many subfolders on each level. Hence, many programmers automatically split up folder structure and file names using hashes (or something similar). Something like this:

1aef3355ccddae231122334455aaeedd.jpg

will be stored at:

1aef/3355/ccdd/ae231122334455aaeedd.jpg

Would that be applicable to Google Cloud Storage too or can we just save everything, let's say all 2 million user profile images, into one bucket and Google takes care of everything else in the background since were talking cloud storage? Anyone experienced limitations in this matter or feels like sharing best practice advice? I did not find any information in the official Google docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real limit to the number of files inside a folder, as Cloud Storage doesn't use folders like a normal OS. The folder is actually just a prefix for the object name. This is touched upon [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#objectnames).

The actual limitations of GCS are explained in the [docs here.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas)

The main reason for splitting objects into folders would be for iterating through them, or listing them. If you have everything in your "root" folder, iterating through 2 million files can take a while, as can listing. Since getting metadata for an object incurs costs, having everything in the "root" folder can incur costs that can be avoided by using folders. See [the pricing article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing) for details.